# Why is this UI update code working?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

From what I understand, you can only update the UI from the main queue, so why is this code working anyway ?

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)) {

            self.myLabel.text = "Updated text"
        }
```

*The queue provided by `QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND` is definitely not the main queue !*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that you can't ever update the UI from a background queue. It's that it isn't defined and it may not work properly so it shouldn't be done.

Comment: Thank you, I thought there would necessarily be a runtime error when doing that !

Comment: In general no but some UIKit code will show a message and it may cause an exception in a future version of iOS.

Comment: But than, tiny bit different question, but what is the point of QOS_USER_INTERACTIVE ? Work submitted to this queue won't happen on the main thread right ? So why is this queue still dedicated to user interactive elements ?

Comment: Because Apple doc says about this QoS "Work that is interacting with the user, such as operating on the main thread, **refreshing the user interface, or performing animations**. If the work doesn’t happen quickly, the user interface may appear frozen. Focuses on responsiveness and performance."

Comment: You are asking about the `NSOperation qualityOfService` property I believe. The `NSQualityOfServiceUserInteractive` value doesn't mean the operation will be run on the main queue, it means the operation is critical to interacting with the user so it needs a high priority. It doesn't mean the operation itself is on the main queue.